# Regex to match everything between

Tags: regex, go

I've been trying at this for an hour, but I'm no regexpert. What I want to do seems fairly simple, but it's turning out a lot more difficult than I would have thought.

Basically I have this:

```
<<< Some code

    def prnt(string)
        print(string)
    end

=====

    def println(string)
        puts(string)
    end

*****
<<< Some more code
...
```

What I want to do is capture everything between the first line `<<< Some code` and the `*****`. There will be lots of blocks like this in a file.

The regex that I have so far is this `(?:<<< .*\r?\n)([\s\S]+)(?:[*]{5})`, but it doesn't really work. Any ideas? The language I'm using it in is Go.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind I figured it out!

`(?:<<< .*\r?\n)([\s\S]*?)(?:[*]{5})`

It seems like the big thing was making the match group in the middle lazy so that it would match as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This captures the target in group 1, but you must use the "dot matches newline" switch "s":

```
<<<[^\r\n]+[\r\n]*(.*?)[*]{5}
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/oNhoeFziff).